# Linux sound lags while copying from USB key

Tags: linux, audio, io

Why did I experienced sound skipping while copying a big file from my USB key onto my computer's drive?

I monitored the system during this I/O operation:

- music was playing from Internet on the browser's flash player,
- CPU was about 75% iowait, 25% user/system time,
- system load was around 4 (on my dual core CPU),
- sound was skipping while data was written on my SSD (that is, for about 1 second every 5 seconds),
- I use the deadline I/O scheduler, pulseaudio and Linux kernel version 3.13.

I'm surprised because:

- playing sound from Internet shouldn't be influenced by disk I/O,
- the CPU was mostly waiting (iowait).

What's wrong then?

Comment: Maybe the browser (or Flash) buffers / caches data on disk? Use e.g. `iotop` to find out.